# Move search bar from header in home page in magento

Tags: magento, search, header, html

I am a new to magento. I wanted to move the search bar from the header to the middle position on home page so that it displays only on the home page.

I've read many related answers on the magento forum but all are trying to edit .mini-search element in boxes.css but unfortunately I don't have any such element in this file.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: what theme are you using?  what version of Magento?

Comment: I am using 1.4 version and default theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to edit `catalogsearch.xml` in your theme's layout folder and delete the following lines:

```
<reference name="header">
     <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

That will remove it from the header of every page.  Now, to insert it into your homepage. Go to the admin under CMS>Pages and select your Home Page.  Paste the lines into the Content section wherever you want the search box to appear:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="home.search" as="homeSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}}
```

Good luck,
JD

Comment: I also wanted to add a background image to it but when I edit the image name from styles.css the changes are not getting reflected back. Can u suggest something plz.

Comment: use Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools or IE Developer Tools to inspect the element and make the changes that you want, then copy them across to the correct css file