# Move search bar from header in home page in magento1.9

Tags: search, header, magento-1.9

I wanted to move the search bar from the header to the middle position on home page so that it displays only on the home page.

I've read many related answers on the magento forum but all are trying to edit .mini-search element in boxes.css but unfortunately not working

So, how can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401745/move-search-bar-from-header-in-home-page-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the block from the header, you can do so by adding the below lines to your local.xml file 
`app/design/frontend/{{PACKAGE}}/{{THEME}}/layout/local.xml`

Add the below lines to the file

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.search" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then you can add the block to whichever handle you would like, or if its easier for yourself you can place the search block within the cms page set as your homepage, using the below line

```
{{block type="core/template" name="custom.search" as="customSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}}
```